# CSS Hover Scaling is unhiding overflow hidden content briefly then re-hiding

Tags: css, transform

I am trying to scale up a linked image and reduce the opacity on hover. I have the image in a container to make it a circle with border-radius and the container has overflow set to hidden. I have everything working except that when I hover, the full image appears for a brief second before the overflow is hidden again. Here is a codepen mockup: http://codepen.io/jphogan/pen/WbxKJG

I have tried a few of the solutions I've found on here including setting the image to display:block. I've also tried setting the background color and overflow hidden to the container rather than the link, but I had the same result. I tried adding overflow hidden to the image itself, though unsurprisingly that did nothing. I just need the excess of the image to stay hidden throughout the transition.

Here is the CSS the way I have it set up now, although I've gone through a number of iterations to try and solve this. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
.solutions_role_container {
    text-align:center;
}

.role_img_container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a.solutions_role_image {
    background:#000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #B1C3DA;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px #C6C6C6;   
}

.solutions_role_image img {
    width:100%;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    transform:scale(1);
}

a.solutions_role_image:hover img {
    opacity:0.7; 
    transform:scale(1.08);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these rules to role_img_container:

```
border-radius: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
```

The `a` and `img` tags should no longer need any css for overflow or border radius.  You could add `z-index: 1` to `solutions_role_img` just to be safe, but I don't think it is necessary

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I had tried those rules on the container, but didn't even think about the z-index. Thanks!!

Comment: Of course! I would definitely remove the border radius from the image though, it seemed to be a little noticeable around the edges almost like it was making a border